# What is going on with my TAR script?

Tags: tar, gzip

This might do better at StackExchange but I use Ubuntu as my file server.

So I'm trying to use `tar` and `gzip` to only backup the last 6 months of changes on my file server and it isn't working. It doesn't `gzip` anything, it puts the tar file in the same directory as the script(not what i want), and it changes the name of the file to part of the tar string.

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash


tod=$(date +%F_%H%M%S)
echo "start"
echo $tod

echo "testing tar, only the last 6 months"
tar -cvf--newer-mtime=08-11-2013 /homedepot/yellowsolo/xz/6months/xz$tod-last6months.tar /homedepot/yellowsolo/xz/official/official /homedepot/yellowsolo/xz/home/home

echo "now zipping"
gzip /homedepot/yellowsolo/xz/6months/xz$tod-last6months.tar.gz

echo $tod
echo "done"
exit
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have the wrong syntax for your tar options. First, you need a space between "-cvf" and "--newer-mtime=08-11-2013", '-cvf --newer-mtime=08-11-2013' and second the date syntax is 20130811 , see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10367037/is-tar-ignoring-after-date-option . As an alternate, and perhaps simpler backup, consider rsync ;)

Comment: I `rsync` everything from another server to this one to archive it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
#!/bin/bash
tod=$(date +%F_%H%M%S)
echo "Start"
echo $tod

echo "testing tar, only the last 6 months"
tar --newer-mtime=20130811 -cvzf /homedepot/yellowsolo/xz/6months/xz$tod-last6months.tar /homedepot/yellowsolo/xz/official/official /homedepot/yellowsolo/xz/home/home

echo "Done"
exit
```

I have cleaned up the errors in the tar command - you need to have `f` option before the filename, and filtered it through gzip (the `z` option).

Comment: +1 for pointing out use of `tar` filename just after `-f` option.

Answer (score 2):

At first you have tried to create a `.tar` file. Apart from the syntax error  bodhi.zazen already pointed out your `tar` file name should come just after `-f` option. As Wilf aptly pointed out in his answer.

```bsh
tar --newer-mtime=08-11-2013 -cvf /homedepot/yellowsolo/xz/6months/xz$tod-last6months.tar /homedepot/yellowsolo/xz/official/official /homedepot/yellowsolo/xz/home/home
```

Next there is another error. You are going to `gzip` `/homedepot/yellowsolo/xz/6months/xz$tod-last6months.tar.gz` but this file does not exist.

Rather you have a file `/homedepot/yellowsolo/xz/6months/xz$tod-last6months.tar`

You should use,

```bsh
gzip /homedepot/yellowsolo/xz/6months/xz$tod-last6months.tar
```

It will create `/homedepot/yellowsolo/xz/6months/xz$tod-last6months.tar.gz`.

**Note:**

You can do it directly,

```bsh
tar --newer-mtime=08-11-2013 -cvzf /homedepot/yellowsolo/xz/6months/xz$tod-last6months.tar.gz /homedepot/yellowsolo/xz/official/official /homedepot/yellowsolo/xz/home/home
```

`-z` switch zip tar simultaneously.

Comment: There was something wrong - there was no space  the `-cvf`. Also, @bodhi was right in that the date syntax was wrong. Good anyway +1

Comment: yes you are correct. at the same time OP was trying to gzip a file that does not exist. is not it?

Comment: Yep :D @souravc